# Как упростить ссылку в браузере при фильтрации?

Tags: php

На сайте можно фильтровать записи (скажем я хочу отфильтровать по цене). Ссылка становится такой:

> http:///mysite.ru/search/transport/cars/c=965&lt=1&sort=new&page=1&p[f]=1&p[t]=2&p[c]=4

Как Вы понимаете, это тихий ужас...

Возможно ли после выполнения фильтрации вместо этой ссылки подставить слово *filter*? Чтобы получилось вот так:

> http:///mysite.ru/search/transport/cars/filter

Comment: Это всё зависит от того на чём сайт работает.. самописный сайт или CMS ?

Comment: чтобы в URL было пусто нужно либо, как уже ответили, делать POST-запросы, либо организовывать все это через ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перейти на `POST`?
Ссылка может быть красивой и лаконичной, но тогда нельзя будет поделится фильтром.
Впрочем, можно добавить функционал типа "Запомнить фильтр", формировать `GUID` и формировать `URI` вида `http://mysite.ru/search/transport/cars/filter/b6dfc394-2ef8-471e-9bf6-9745a2d92d75`.
Но это если только специально для поделится, а так `URI` будет `http://mysite.ru/search/transport/cars/filter`.

---

Детали реализации на Вас, ибо мы ничего не знаем о CMS.

Comment: Поделиться фильтром и не надо :) Главное, что-бы после выбора нужных опций в фильтре, ссылка была красивой :)

Comment: Тогда `POST` Вам поможет.

Answer (score 0):

Если использувуете сервер Apache с PHP, было бы полезно изменить ваши файли [.htaccess](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html). (вот [перевод статьи на русском, Google Переводчик](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=en&tl=ru&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=https%3A%2F%2Fhttpd.apache.org%2Fdocs%2F2.4%2Fhowto%2Fhtaccess.html&edit-text=&act=url))

Например, в каталоге `/search/transport/`, сделайте новый файл `.htaccess`. В файле, напишите что-то похожий на этом:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^cars/(.*)$ /index.php?car=$1 [QSA]
```

Тогда, когда вы посещаете `http://mysite.ru/search/transport/cars/1`, сервер увидит `http://mysite.ru/search/transport/index.php?car=1`

Comment: автор вроде написал, какой url есть,и какой он хочет получит. вы думаете с помощью mod_rewrite это достижимо? Если, то приведите пример правил содержащих url из вопроса, а не банальный `cars/1`

Comment: всю ночью сидел, сомневаюсь, что .htaccess можно добиться такого результата.. скорей всего придётся переделывать/переписывать сам код

Comment: извините. жаль, что не смог вам помочь(